# TCP Broadcast preserve 1 main host, ignoring the rest

Tags: networking, tcp

I'm working on a live client-server system using TCP. The system must ready 24/7 with cut-off time 30 minutes per day.

For some reasons like testing, I want to add some 'shadow servers' to the system, so that clients will send request to main server and shadow servers. While the request should be sent to all server, only the reply from main server that matters thus should be sent back to client. Reply from shadow servers should be ignored.

Moreover, starting and stopping shadows server mustn't do any harm to the system. If a shadows is up, it will receive request, if it's down, nothing will happen to client-main server.

Is there a way for me to do this without changing either client or main server code?

Comment: 'TCP broadcast' is already a contradiction in terms. TCP is a point-to-point protocol.

Comment: @EJP are you suggest that there's no way without moving to UDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in client or server code because TCP is point-to-point only.

Perhaps what you want is a "frontend load balancer" that keeps track of what servers are running and forwards incoming requests to one of those.

On the high end, a [NetScaler](http://www.citrix.com/products/netscaler-application-delivery-controller/overview.html) does all this.  Though I haven't personally configured one of these devices, I expect it can have both "primary" and "backup" servers.  When I used them, it distributed the load evenly between many servers.  It can also be arranged in "high availability pairs" where two of them are connected with one as a "hot standby" in the case where the primary fails.

You probably don't need anything this sophisticated but it serves to illustrate the point.

Comment: I don't want to do load balancing, since the shadows server isn't there to backup main server. It's there for other purpose such as testing newly build main server for regression, logging what message come and go, etc

Comment: In order to compare results from two servers, you need a third.  The third server accepts all incoming connections and opens **two** backend connections, one to the main server and one to the shadow, forwarding the request to both.  It then forwards the reply from the main back to the client but keeps the result around to compare with the reply from the shadow.  This third server can also log everything.